# Analysis of land use compositional data

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, model, compositional-data

I am struggling in finding the suitable method to analyse a land use dataset.

The dataset is composed of land use data for several crop groups and for several global countries. For each country, I have information about land use under conventional and under organic production. The different countries are clustered in global climate regions. Data are expressed in percentages of area cultivated for each crop group.

Here an example of a few lines of the dataset:

```
Country climatic_region           system    Berries cereals Citrus  Coconut pulses  Fruit.temperate Fruit.tropical  Grapes  nuts    Oilseeds    Olives  rootcrops   Strawberries    Tea     Textile Tobacco vegetables
Albania subtropics_winter_rainfall conv     0.00     0.48   0.00    0.00    0.07    0.05             0.04           0.03    0.01    0.01        0.13    0.04         0.00           0.00    0.00    0.01    0.13
Algeria subtropics_winter_rainfall conv     0.00     0.66   0.01    0.00    0.02    0.04             0.05           0.02    0.01    0.00        0.08    0.03         0.00           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.08
```

I would like to know if there are significant differences between each crop category for different production systems (i.e. Organic vs Conventional), and for the different global climatic regions. For example, I would like to know if the percent amount of land use under "cereals", differs between `systems:climatic_regions`.

This would mean to run an ANOVA including a interaction term `system*climatic_region` using a model like `cereals ~ system*climatic_region`.

Should I analyse my dataset as compositional data (e.g. by using the **compositions** R package)?
How do I handle the several zeros in my dataset (which are true zeros)?

Comment: Have you tried to use zCompositions package? It is a package to deal with zeros in compositional data analysis.